# (Prolog) Get numbers within a range from a list

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to get all numbers between 10 and 40 (inclusive) from a list, and outputting to another list. So far my code sort of works but does not yield the desired result. The catch is that I can't use system predicates.

```
rangeTenForty([], List2).
rangeTenForty([H|T], List2) :- H >= 10, T =< 40, rangeTenForty(T, List2).
rangeTenForty([H|T], List2) :- rangeTenForty(T, List2).
```

A few conditions:

`?- rangeTenForty([400, 13, 20, 50], X).` returns the answer X = [13, 20], a query

`?- rangeTenForty([100, 5, 77], X).` returns the answer X = [], but a query

`?- rangeTenForty([12,25,2004], [12,2004]).` must return the answer no.

Any help is really really really appreciated. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct a few things.

```
rangeTenForty([], []).
rangeTenForty([H|T], [H|L]):- H >= 10, H =< 40, rangeTenForty(T, L).
rangeTenForty([H|T], L):- (H < 10;H > 40), rangeTenForty(T, L).
```